# Saying Amein in a Tefilla

Tags: tefilla, minhag, amen

In certain prayers, the congregation interjects the word Amein after certain words/phrases. In The Ya'aleh V'yavo, I hear it in the last section, amidst these three statements

> זָכְרֵנוּ ה' אֱלהֵינוּ בּו לְטובָה. וּפָקְדֵנוּ בו לִבְרָכָה. וְהושִׁיעֵנוּ בו לְחַיִּים

I also hear it on Rosh Chodesh, during Musaf ([here](https://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Hallel-Musaf-Rosh-%E1%B8%A4odesh-Nusa%E1%B8%A5-Ha-Ari-%E1%B8%A4aBaD.pdf), page 12).

And I recall it on Shabbat/Rosh Chodesh in Musaf

> רְצֵה בִמְנוּחָתֵנוּ וְחַדֵּשׁ עָלֵינוּ בְּיום הַשַּׁבָּת הַזֶּה אֶת הַחדֶשׁ הַזֶּה. לְטובָה וְלִבְרָכָה. לְששון וּלְשמְחָה. לִישׁוּעָה וּלְנֶחָמָה. לְפַרְנָסָה וּלְכַלְכָּלָה. לְחַיִּים וּלְשָׁלום. לִמְחִילַת חֵטְא וְלִסְלִיחַת עָון

Finally, I think it is said at the end of Birchat Hachodesh

> יְחַדְּשֵׁהוּ הַקָּדושׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל עַמּו בֵּית יִשרָאֵל בְּכָל מָקום שֶׁהֵם. לְטובָה וְלִבְרָכָה. לְששון וּלְשמְחָה. לִישׁוּעָה וּלְנֶחָמָה. לְפַרְנָסָה טובָה וּלְכַלְכָּלָה. לְחַיִּים וּלְשָׁלום. לִשְׁמוּעות טובות. וְלִבְשורות טובות. בחורף - וְלִגְשָׁמִים בְּעִתָּם. וְלִרְפוּאָה שְׁלֵמָה. וְלִגְאוּלָה קְרובָה

I don't know if there are other instances (or other holidays) in which this practice finds a home. If I have forgotten any, apologies.

I am not sure where this practice originates but I'm wondering why it ISN'T the case in other situations where a litany of wishes is used. Specifically, at the outset of Birchat Hachodesh, I don't recall that the word Amein is said by the congregation

> וְתִתֶּן לָנוּ חַיִּים אֲרוּכִּים. חַיִּים שֶׁל שָׁלום. חַיִּים שֶׁל טובָה. חַיִּים שֶׁל בְּרָכָה. חַיִּים שֶׁל פַּרְנָסָה. חַיִּים שֶׁל חִלּוּץ עֲצָמות. חַיִּים שֶׁיֵשׁ בָּהֶם יִרְאַת שָׁמַיִם וְיִרְאַת חֵטְא. חַיִּים שֶׁאֵין בָּהֶם בּוּשָׁה וּכְלִמָּה. חַיִּים שֶׁל עשֶׁר וְכָבוד. חַיִּים שֶׁתְּהֵא בָנוּ אַהֲבַת תּורָה וְיִרְאַת שָׁמַיִם. חַיִּים שֶׁיִּמָלְאוּ מִשְׁאֲלות לִבֵּנוּ לְטובָה

Are there rules for when this should or should not be inserted or why it has become accepted to say it in some cases but not others?

Comment: Also birchas tal/geshem

Comment: Nice Q. I'll see if beureihatefillah has something to say about this. Sephardim tend to have far more responses than Ashkenazim do, overall.

Comment: Many Sephardic congregations add _amen_ in many lists of blessings, like in the last part of the central benediction of the _amida_ on the sabbath and holidays ("קדשנו במצותיך ותן חלקנו בתורתך שבענו...‏"). In fact, I suspect the rule for such congregations is simple: add it to any list of blessings. If you're asking specifically about Ashkenazic congregations, I recommend you [edit] to indicate as much.

Comment: @msh210 do Sephardic congregations add it to the first part of Birchat Hachodesh?

Comment: (re your comment addressed to me) I don't recall. Probably — if they say that paragraph at all (which I also don't recall).

Comment: *Ta'amei Haminhagim* states to respond *Amen* in *Ya'aleh Veyavo*. He doesn't state why. I haven't yet researched the others. Of course, even when people give you a personal bracha, it's common to respond "Amen", so perhaps this is a precedent? though, I agree that it seems to be reserved to a few situations such as those that you mentioned.

Comment: @DanF but then why not in the other I mentioned?

Comment: A good question, but the title needs to be more specific, like "multiple Amens in one Brocho" or something.

Comment: Perhaps it's various customs balancing communal prayer and brevity of tefillah?

Comment: Also היום תאמצנו at the end of R"H and Y"K musaf. What's interesting about birchas hachodesh is that it ends in ונאמר אמן but we still throw in extra amens. I guess that's true for parts of kaddish too.

Comment: The second part of Birchat Hachodesh יְחַדְּשֵׁהוּ is similar to Rosh Chodesh in Musaf רְצֵה בִמְנוּחָתֵנוּ, this would be a reason why we dont say Amein by וְתִתֶּן לָנוּ חַיִּים אֲרוּכִּים from Birchat Hachodesh.

Answer (score 1):

[Magen Avraham 215:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen%20Avraham%20215:3)

> When one hears someone praying, speaking, or blessing the people of Israel, even without mentioning the name, one must respond 'Amen.' Therefore, the custom has spread to answer 'Amen' after the 'Harahaman's.

[Haemek Sh'elah 53:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Haamek_Sheilah_on_Sheiltot_d%27Rav_Achai_Gaon.53.2.1)

> It doesn't fit into the category of an absolute obligation. It's just a measure of piety.

I have heard in the name of Rabbi Asher Hatchuel that this is *not* speaking about the middle of tefillah (ya'aleh v'yavo). In the middle of tefillah it would be considered an interruption and should not be done. In places where it is already the custom to do it then one can respond Amen.